# How to set texture on a shape drawn by glDrawArrays()?

Tags: java, opengl, jogl, texture-mapping, texture2d

I have a 3D cube which drawn by vertex array  -

```
public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
...
float[] cubeVertices = {...}; // vertex coordinates (x,y,z) 
FloatBuffer tmpVerticesBuf = BufferUtil
                .newFloatBuffer(cubeVertices.length);
for (int i = 0; i < cubeVertices.length; i++) {
            tmpVerticesBuf.put(cubeVertices[i]);
        }
tmpVerticesBuf.rewind();
gl.glEnableClientState(GL.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY); 
gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL.GL_FLOAT, 0, tmpVerticesBuf);
}

public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
...
gl.glDrawArrays(GL.GL_QUADS, 0, 24);
...
}
```

Now I want to set a texture picture on the face's of this cube such that it will be same texture of to all the cube face's . So far I did in the `init()`  -

```
public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) { 
...
try {
                    // retrieve the image .  
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getClassLoader()
                    .getResource("floor.jpg"));
            DataBufferByte dbb = (DataBufferByte) image.getRaster()
                    .getDataBuffer();
            byte[] data = dbb.getData();
            ByteBuffer pixels = BufferUtil.newByteBuffer(data.length);
            pixels.put(data);
            pixels.flip();

        } catch (GLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        m_textutureIntBuf = IntBuffer.allocate(1); // m_textutureIntBuf type  IntBuffer
        gl.glGenTextures(1, m_textutureIntBuf);
        gl.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_textutureIntBuf.get(0));
        gl.glTexImage2D(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL.GL_RGB, 256, 256, 0, GL.GL_RGB,
                GL.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, m_pixels);
        gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,
                GL.GL_LINEAR);
        gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
                GL.GL_NEAREST);
        gl.glEnable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

What I have to do now about the `gl.glTexCoordPointer()` `gl.glEnableClientState()` in order to get what I mentioned before  about the texture ?

Comment: [https://www.khronos.org/.../glTexCoordPointer.xml](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTexCoordPointer.xml)

Answer (score 3):

Well you need to create an array for the `Texture Coordinates` too.

At the *"... DATA ..."* you need to add your U, V coordinates. All Vertices have a U, V coordinate. So the `tex_coord_size` is basically `2 * vertices_count`.

```
int tex_coord_size = x; // Whatever size you want according to your `Vertices`

FloatBuffer tex_coord_data = BufferTools.createFloatBuffer(tex_coord_size);
tex_coord_data.put(new float[] { ... DATA ... });
tex_coord_data.flip();


int vbo_tex_coord_handle = glGenBuffers();
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_tex_coord_handle );
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, tex_coord_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

And then for rendering you need to add, to your current rendering.

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo_tex_coord_handle);
glTexCoordPointer(tex_coord_size, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0l);

glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
```

After you've called glDrawArrays, you need to call `glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);` also of course.

Comment: what is the `{...DATA...}` ? same coordinates as as the cube vertex's  ?